# google social login not working in ionic capacitor using codetrix-studio capacitor-google-auth

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, capacitor

in the capacitor.config.json

```js
"GoogleAuth": {
  "scopes": ["profile","email"],
  "serverClientId": "KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com"
}
```

in index.html

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

in android folder string.xml file

```html
<string name="server_client_id">KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

and in our page .ts file to get detail of google user detail

```js
const user = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
```

and I have an error in android something went wrong.

**anyone has any idea how to solve this situation**

Comment: did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add these lines of code in ***android/app/src/main/java/com/appName/app/MainActivity.java***

```
package com.growyd.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.codetrixstudio.capacitor.GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Initialize bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      add(GoogleAuth.class);
    }});
  }
}
```

In this link are the steps to configure the library.

my reference: https://devdactic.com/capacitor-google-sign-in/

Comment: if I put this code in my MainActivity.java file I got. the error on the console 
"Something Went Wrong" like this

Comment: package com.growyd.app; <- you must change the first line with your Package name (Sorry, I forgot to change this line).

Comment: Thanks, it's working for android but if I build in ios I for errors like this 

`in APP_PATH/ios/App/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.
framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDEMMErrorHandler_3a47e13d8ca81b41e9cdb7ef5468004a.o),
building for iOS Simulator,but linking in object file built for iOS, file 
'APP_PATH/ios/App/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' 
for architecture arm64`

can you help with this also?

Comment: try with update the .plist files and maybe use a different version of XCode, It is very important update the cocoapods dependencies. (sorry for late)

Comment: I am using Xcode v13.1 and I also try with v12 but same issue.

Comment: this solution not working, any other updates ???